# Best way to scrape Highcharts data?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, highcharts

I have read a few questions about this, but none of the answers are helpful to this particular case.

I am trying to get the data from the Highchart at https://www.coindesk.com/indices/xbx/

I have been stuck analyzing the site source code for many hours and can't seem to find any leads where to start.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The data is loaded asynchronously using ajax. Take a look at the connection tab in the Dev Tools (filter by XHR). For example, one of the urls is https://production.api.coindesk.com/v2/exchange-rates

Comment: What have you tried so far / what things have you noticed?

Comment: BrokenBenchmark, I noticed that when I load Elements in console tools, I can search for a price on the chart and see a date and price span element that has the data.

Comment: IT goldman thank you.

Comment: I solved it. If you look at the tab IT goldman mentioned, it shows the API call being made to get the data.